# Regex For value Currency

Tags: regex

I'm really bad at regex and was wondering if anyone could help me with this.  I need to accept a value where $,€, and £ are allowed but not required with a min 5.00 (.00 is not required but is allowed) and 2,000 ( comma is not required but is allowed).

Some examples of valid inputs

```
$5
€5
£5
$5.00
5
1000
1,000
1,000.00
```

Comment: Is the minimum 5.00 or 2,000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to allow values like £5.32:

`^[$€£]?(\d+([\.,]\d{2})?)$`

If not:

`^[$€£]?(\d+([\.,]00)?)$`

Once you've checked whether it's formatted correctly using the regex, you can go on to check whether `5 < int(value) < 2000` using the first returned group of the regex.

EDIT: Having thought about it, here's a regex which will take care of the bounding too:

`^[$€£]?((([1-5],?)?\d{2,3}|[5-9])(\.\d{2})?)$`

Comment: Comma is for thousands; not for fractional part.

Comment: Hmm, I tried your new edit and I'm still getting false return when I'm testing the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

[RegexMagic](http://www.regexmagic.com) to the rescue:

```
\b(?:[$£€])? *(?:2,?000|1,?[0-9]{3}|[1-9][0-9]{1,2}|[5-9])(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?\b
```

Do you agree that doing all this in a regex (while possible) is not really a very good idea?