# How to find nodes with Python string matching functions in Networkx?

Tags: python, regex, networkx, shortest-path

Given a dependency parse graph, if I want to find the shortest path length between two fixed nodes, this is how I've coded it:

```
nx.shortest_path_length (graph, source='cost', target='20.4')
```

My question here is: What if I want to match for all sentences in the graph or collection a target with any number formatted approximately as a currency? Would I have to first find every node in the graph that is a currency, and then iterate over the set of currency values?

It would be ideal to have:

```
nx.shortest_path_length (graph, source='cost', target=r'^[$€£]?(\d+([\.,]00)?)$')
```

Or from [@bluepnume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010671) `^[$€£]?((([1-5],?)?\d{2,3}|[5-9])(\.\d{2})?)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in two steps, without having to loop over.

- Step 1: Calculate the shortest distance from your 'cost' node to all reachable nodes.
- Step 2: Subset (using regex) just the currency nodes that you are interested in.

Here's an example to illustrate.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re

g = nx.DiGraph()    
#create a dummy graph for illustration
g.add_edges_from([('cost','apples'),('cost', 'of'),
                  ('$2', 'pears'),('lemon', '£1.414'),
                  ('apples', '$2'),('lemon', '£1.414'),
                  ('€3.5', 'lemon'),('pears', '€3.5'),
                 ], distance=0.5) # using a list of edge tuples & specifying distance
g.add_edges_from([('€3.5', 'lemon'),('of', '€3.5')], 
                 distance=0.7)
nx.draw(g, with_labels=True)
```

which produces:

[image]

Now, you can calculate the shortest paths to your nodes of interest, subsetting using regex like you wanted to.

```
paths = nx.single_source_dijkstra_path(g, 'cost')
lengths=nx.single_source_dijkstra_path_length(g,'cost', weight='distance')

currency_nodes = [ n for n in lengths.keys() if re.findall('(\$|€|£)',n)]

[(n,len) for (n,len) in lengths.items() if n in currency_nodes]
```

produces:

```
[('$2', 1.0), ('€3.5', 1.2), ('£1.414', 2.4)]
```

Hope that helps you move forward.